# Use of Multi Threading for printing Odd and Even Numbers

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, java-threads, thread-synchronization

I'm pretty new to threads and just trying to get a grip on the basics.So, I tried the following code to print odd and even numbers one after the other.

But I'm getting a null pointer.

public class P {

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

     Print print = new Print(false);
     Even e =new Even();
     Odd o = new Odd();  
     e.start();
     o.start();
}
```

}

class Even extends Thread
{
    Print print;

```
public void run()
{
  try {
    print.printeven();

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

}

class Odd extends Thread
{
    Print print;

```
public void run()
{
  try {
    print.printodd();

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

}

class Print {

```
public  boolean flag=false;

Print(boolean flag){

    this.flag=flag;
}

synchronized void printodd() throws InterruptedException
   {

    for(int i=1;i<10;i=i+2)
        if(!flag)
        {
        System.out.println(i);
        notifyAll();
        flag=true;
        }
        else
        {
            wait();
        }
   }

synchronized void printeven() throws InterruptedException
   {

    for(int i=2;i<=10;i=i+2)
        if(flag)
        {
        System.out.println(i);
        notifyAll();
        flag=false;
        }
        else
        {
            wait();
        }
   }
```

}

If someone could explain in detail what I'm doing wrong here and give a basic idea how to go about debugging this.

Comment: you didn't initialize `print` instance in `Odd` and `even` classes, it's always null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not instantiated Print instance in both ODD and EVEN classes.

Do this for both Even and Odd constructors.

```
public Odd(Print print) 
{ 
  this.print = print;
}
```

When instantiating do like this.

```
 Print print = new Print(false);
 Even e =new Even(print);
 Odd o = new Odd(print);
```

Comment: Thanks...It worked i thought there must be some thread related problem.

Answer (score 0):

See You are doing Nothing with

`Print print = new Print(false);  // this statement`

in main() method.

pass the "print" object to Odd and Even class Constructor.

You are getting Null pointer Because you are not initialising print Object Odd and Even class.